# Unable to decode log with type string due to (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber")

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I cannot decode the log for the parameters of the type string.

```js
const event = {
topics: ["0x5820e4ce60ef5cafebaa0b89e2b7efb3d2555b4b24735f879981e488b863933f4b00"],
data: '0x5860000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044b69746100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    };
    
const inputDefs = [
   {
      indexed: false,
      internalType: 'string',
      name: 'name',
      type: 'string',
   },
];
    
    const decoded = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(inputDefs, event.data, event.topics);

console.log(decoded);
```

Getting this error:

```js
{
   reason: 'overflow',
   code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
   fault: 'overflow',
   operation: 'toNumber',
   value: '39973147993546167072492522656807788502080995682914003308543218698044229812224'
}
```

Comment: Can you show the event definition in the smart contract? Also, whare where the parameter values that you passed to the event when emitting it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the ABI for the contract address you are pointing at, I would assume that your `typesArray` is in the wrong format, hence you are not following the ERC20 compliance required to decode. Likely, you are **trying to convert a `hex` value to a number which is in fact `bytes32`**, resulting in overflow.

By looking at your `typesArray`, and the `topics` + `data` being presented by the log, I will also assume that this array doesn't appropriately address the **four** parameters being passed in `topics` and `data` (this you can derive just by looking at the following byte code:

```
data: '0x5860000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044b69746100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
};
```

Subsequently, you'll run into issues until these types are correctly defined.

Go to the contract ABI and ensure you have a **full `types` array** meeting the 'types' defined in the ABI.